# Which server was logged into by specific user

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, user-accounts

How do I go about finding out which server was logged into last using a specific user account on the domain?

Comment: by auditing and reporting

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin, does windows 2008 r2 have a built in way of producing such an audit report?  Or will I  have to buy a 3rd party took to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean which domain controller the user authenticated against when they last logged on to their workstation?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the Event Viewer, if you want to check manually.  Under Windows Logs > Security you can see both successful and failed logins and you can see logouts.  See the Task Category column in the screen capture. [image: EventViewer].

You could write some PowerShell code or .NET / WMI code to pull relevant "most recent" items across multiple servers if you have WinRM enabled and you're authorized.

UPDATE: This is some Powershell script to get the successful logins in the last 30 minutes.  I am filtering by time and by `InstanceId` which is the id associated with different classes of events.  On my server, `4624` represents `Logon` Task Category, but you should validate that on your own server and tweak the code as needed.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -EntryType SuccessAudit -InstanceId 4624 -After (([System.DateTime]::Now).AddMinutes(-30))
```

Comment: you don't even need winrm, just event viewer permissions on the other servers, simplest is to set up a subscription

Comment: Agreed but if you're reaching across server to discover information you may want to take some action as a result -- which may require remote management.  i usually just set it up, but definitely not a MUST.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad idea, but if you're just auditing it's not required, and very simply to do without a line of code with the event collector, drop the resulting export into excel and analyze away.  One of the OP comments was what is the built in tool for this- that's what I'm suggesting you consider putting in your answer- powershell is most certainly not the best solution in this case.